# Attach an event handler to a StopWatch

Tags: c#, vb.net, stopwatch

I would like to attach an event handler to a Stop Watch. Can someone please provide a code snippet in C# or VB?

I'v Bing'd it with no luck.

Comment: There is no such thing... How do you expect the event handler to work? Maybe there's something else you can do instead.

Comment: What event handler do you want to use?  Also, what do you mean by stop watch?

Answer (score 4):

Have a Bing for **Timer** instead... That ought get you there... One decent one in particular: http://dotnetperls.com/timer

Comment: @Bram: Also be aware that there are a few different Timer implementations (e.g. System.Threading.Timer and System.Timers.Timer and System.Windows.Forms.Timer). Choose wisely...

Answer (score 0):

here is an example of a Timer I use for a backup program I wrote that will start in 5 seconds after instantiating it and fire the callback (tick) every hour:

```
    private System.Threading.Timer AutoRunTimer; 

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mybackups = new BackupService();
        AutoRunTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(tick, "", new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5), new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0));     
    }

    private void tick(object data)
    {
        if (DateTime.Now.Hour == 1 && DateTime.Now.Subtract(lastRun).Hours >= 1) // run backups at first opportunity after 1 am
        {
            startBackup("automatically");
        }
    }
```