# Running a loop for specific time using timer in windows form application C#

Tags: c#, timer

I'm trying to make some calculations repeatedly for a specific amount of time (the `time` is variable and provided by the user.)

I tried using timer available in windows form application toolbox in visual studio, but there seems to be a problem. The program gets stuck when I start the timer and associate the variable for `time` with the while loop; the `time` variable is being decremented in each tick event of timer and I need to run the while loop as long as time is greater than 0.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (time == 0)
            timer1.Stop();

        else
        {
            time--;
            textBoxTime.Text = time.ToString();
        }

    }
```

and here is the while loop that blocks the program

```
while (time>0)
{
   computations();
}
```

Comment: How often do you need to run `computations`? Is it only when the time changes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> i'm trying to make some calculations repeatedly for a specific amount of time the time is variable and provided by the user.

Rather than use a timer to count down the time for you in ticks, I would suggest you have the loop itself note when it started, check the current time at each loop iteration, and see if it has been running long enough.

> and here is the while loop that blocks the program

Presumably you are performing the calculation on your UI thread.  This will prevent any UI messages from being processed, including the timer ticks, thus making the application unresponsive.

Start a separate thread to perform the actual calculation. [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) is a common means to do this from WinForms, though there are many approaches.

Comment: I believe Eric is correct.  Where is your "while (time>0)" loop located?  If it's on the UI thread, then the Timer Tick event handler will never get called.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Timer class for this a simple sample is this:

```
Clock=new Timer();
Clock.Interval=time;
Clock.Start();
Clock.Tick+=new EventHandler(OnTimer_Tick);
```

Where OnTimer_Tick is a function that does some work

```
public void OnTimer_Tick(object sender,EventArgs eArgs)
{
//do computations here
}
```

Here is a related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862177/attach-an-event-handler-to-a-stopwatch)

Edit: Your while loop is running faster than a tick so you are running a lot of loops. I updated timer to use the time variable as it's interval value and get rid of the while loop and do the computations on each tick.

Comment: the problem seems to be with the while loop the timer works fine i've checked it! the while loop is not working for some reason and program is jammed

Comment: I believe you want to check the value of the timer's ticks against your time variable?  That will cause it to run until the timer reaches whatever the time variable holds.  In the case of the while loop, you are going to hit an infinite loop every single time since there is no exit condition.

Comment: but i'm decreasing the value of time with each tick so while the calculations are performed the timer is decreasing the value of time until it reaches 0 and that's the exit condition.

Comment: are you decreasing inside of the computations function?  Or, are you saying that you have an event handler on the Timer object's Tick event that decrease the global time variable's value?

Comment: I have an event handler on the Timer object's Tick event that decrease the global time variable's value
'private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (time == 0)
            timer1.Stop();

        else
        {
            time--;
            textBoxTime.Text = time.ToString();
        }

    }'

Comment: Ok, so I made a test project and I realized that your while loop is running much faster than a tick, so your while loop is running 10-20 iterations (maybe more) before the tick event fires.  You could do your while loop computation inside the tick event handler instead and set the Timer interval to your time value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Stopwatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Also it's better put sleep in loop to avoid takes all your machine resource

```
 var sw = new Stopwatch();
 sw.Start();
 while(sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds < 100 /*Time in second*/)
 {
    /// TODO
    Thread.Sleep(100 /*Time in millisecond*/);
 }
 sw.Stop();
```